# What type of fuse for mini split?

Tags: electrical, mini-split

I have a fused disconnect installed for a mini split on a 25A circuit.

Should I use a FRN-R or NON 25A fuse?

I believe it should be FRN-R since that's for protection of a motor, but looking for an idiot check.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the nameplate on the minisplit please? It may be you don't need a fuse here at all...

Comment: What does the mfr spec?  If not posted or in your owner’s manual, check online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely use FRN fuses, they are time delay. NON's are fast acting, good for solid state and resistive (linear) loads. Wouldn't put NON's anywhere near a motor.

Comment: FWIW A properly sized breaker may render fuses unnecessary if the label specifies "maximum overcurrent protection" (vs. max fuse size). If fuses are not needed then buying the maximum fuse size that will fit your disconnect (30A?) might be good to prevent pointless future fuse replacement.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and is indeed the case. It specifies a MOP of 25A and does not say fuses are needed. I just ended up with a fused disconnect. Disconnect is rated to 30A so as long as I have a 25A breaker then I can go with the max fuse as you suggest. Thanks!